# Fetching Table Header and Table Data from Mysql Database

Tags: php, html, sql

i am fetching both table header and table data from a database .
the result from the table data depends on the result from the header ,
i am finding it difficult to call the table row  between the table header and the table data below is my code

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); mysql_select_db("javanet");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from course_pos_map inner join courses on         
course_pos_map.course_id=courses.course_id where dept_id=1");
echo "<table border=1><tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<th>$row[alias]</th>"; # this is the table header , tr is suppose to come     
here so as to break table row below
$csql=mysql_query("select * from student_course_regs where    
 co_pos_map_id='$row[co_map_id]'");
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($csql))
{
    echo "<td>$row2[total_score]<td>"; # this is the table row, it is suppose 
   to be under the header
}
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for as muh i m able to understand ur question. u didnot use tr tag
try this code and please dont forget to vote if i m right

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); mysql_select_db("javanet");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from course_pos_map inner join courses on         
course_pos_map.course_id=courses.course_id where dept_id=1");
echo "<table border=1><tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<tr><th>$row[alias]</th></tr>"; # this is the table header , tr is suppose to come here so as to break table row below
$csql=mysql_query("select * from student_course_regs where co_pos_map_id='$row[co_map_id]'");
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($csql))
{
    echo "<tr><td>$row2[total_score]<td></tr>"; # this is the table row, it is suppose 
   to be under the header
}
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: didn't work out, the rows are vertical instead of horizontal .

Comment: Then the previous one was right. Can you show me the output?

Comment: use td tag instead of th
<td> <b> </b> </td>

Comment: this is the output i got from your code . I need it to be horizontal.

MTH 2351

60 
140 141 123 58 
113 0 
80

MTH 1111

53 
140 141 123 41 
113 0 
80